# Maximal number of $k$-subsets of an $n$-set such that any two subsets meet in at most $(k-2)$ points

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory

I am interested in the maximal number of $k$-subsets of an $n$-set such that any two subsets meet in at most $(k-2)$ points. I found that for $k=3$ and $k=4$, we have the sequences http://oeis.org/A001839 and http://oeis.org/A001843 as solutions which gives the impression that higher orders should be obtainable via $A(n,4,k)$ but this seems to be complicated when I look at the research invested in $A$.

"A binary constant weight code of word length $n$ and weight $w$ and minimum
distance $d$ is a collection of $(0,1)$-vectors of length $n$, all having $w$ ones and
$n - w$ zeros, such that any two of these vectors differ in at least $d$ places. The
maximum size of such a code is denoted by $A(n; d;w)$."
The definition of $A$ can be found here [https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/preprints/cw4p.pdf](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/preprints/cw4p.pdf).

I tried to say something about cases $k>5$ using the [Erdös-Ko-Rado Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem) but I was not really succesfull. Is my intuition right, that $A(n,4,k)$ described exactly the quantity, which I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for constant weight codes with maximum size given by $A(n,4,k).$ Yes this is a very hard problem in terms of constructions in general.

There is the following paper [available online here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/preprints/cw4p.pdf) which has some results:

Some new distance-4 constant weight codes
A. E. Brouwer & T. Etzion
2010-02-18

Abstract

Improved binary constant weight codes with minimum distance 4 and
length at most 28 are constructed. A table with bounds on the chromatic
number of small Johnson graphs is given.

The paper has been published see [here](https://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/amc.2011.5.417) and also cited 10 times according to that link. I suggest you check out those links to see if improved bounds or constructions are available.